# Do you have something like this vs Do you have something like these

Tags: grammar, american-english

If I’m looking for a pair of shoes and I show them the picture of the shoes, do I say:

1. Do you have something like this?
2. Do you have something like these?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

They both sound good and natural to me: this (pair) or these (shoes).

Comment: A pair like this, or shoes like these.